# Definite integral convergence answer check

Tags: convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

this problem is part of my homework assignment and I would like you guys to see if I'm right. So I need to find out for which $a$ is the integral

$$\int^{1/2}_0{\frac{(1-\cos{x})^a(1-x)^3}{\ln^2{(1-x)}}}dx$$

convergent. 
So what I did was use that

$$1 - \cos{x} \to {\frac{x^2}2}$$

as we're approaching $0$, and so the integral was equivalent to

$$\int^{1/2}_0{\frac{x^{2a}}{\ln^2{(1-x)}}}dx$$

then I switched $x$ with $-y$ and got

$$\int^{0}_\frac{-1}2{\frac{y^{2a}}{\ln^2{(1+y)}}}dy$$

and then used

$$\ln{(x+1)} \to x$$

and got

$$\int^{0}_\frac{-1}2{\frac{y^{2a}}{y^2}}dy = \int^{0}_\frac{-1}2{y^{2a-2}}dy = \int^{0}_\frac{-1}2{\frac{1}{y^{2-2a}}}dy$$

hence it is convergent for $a > \frac{1}2$
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I get, using the Taylor Series approximations for the various functions involved, we have :

$\left ( \frac{(1-\cos x)^{a}}{\ln (1-x)} \right )\left ( \frac{(1-x)^{3}}{\ln (1-x))} \right )\approx \left ( \frac{x^{2a}}{2^{a}(-x-(\frac{x^{2}}{2}))} \right )\left ( \frac{(1-x)^{3}}{(-x-(\frac{x^{2}}{2}))} \right )\approx \left ( \frac{-x^{2a}}{2^{a}} \right )\left ( \frac{1-3x}{-x} \right )=(1-3x)\frac{x^{2a-1}}{2^{a}}\approx \frac{x^{2a-1}}{2^{a}}$

The integral is then approximately $\frac{1}{2^{a}}\lim _{m\rightarrow 0^{+}}\int_{m} ^{1/2}x^{2a-1}dx=\lim _{m\rightarrow 0^{+}}\frac{1}{2a2^{a}}\left ( 1/2-m^{2a} \right )$ so the integral converges when $a>0$.